# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'manage' with Flask app on Heroku

Tags: python, python-3.x, heroku, web-deployment

I tired deploying a Python webapp that I made using the Flask framework to Heroku, but whenever I try to access it via the link they provided me I get an application error. I ran `heroku logs --tail` and this is what I got:

First error:

```
at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"host=raymoun17.herokuapp.com request_id=2ccdd1b6-cdf6-4a95-8f41-f7f53dcbe033 fwd="41.104.147.72" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Second error:

```
at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=raymoun17.herokuapp.com request_id=ab94815a-226b-4286-859c-738f4595ac0f fwd="41.104.147.72" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Third error:

```
at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=raymoun17.herokuapp.com request_id=dd14b715-3e8d-4c51-ad8f-dc26acde85fa fwd="41.104.147.72" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Here is the full error log:

```
2019-07-07T18:36:40.664350+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-07-07 18:36:40 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2019-07-07T18:36:40.689093+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-07-07 18:36:40 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2019-07-07T18:36:40.689178+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-07-07 18:36:40 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2019-07-07T19:20:22.506556+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-07-07T19:20:26.657157+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn manage:app`
2019-07-07T19:20:29.412714+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-07-07T19:20:29.392349+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2019-07-07T19:20:29.125129+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-07-07 19:20:29 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
2019-07-07T19:20:29.125720+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-07-07 19:20:29 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:7458 (4)
2019-07-07T19:20:29.125871+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-07-07 19:20:29 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2019-07-07T19:20:29.130277+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-07-07 19:20:29 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2019-07-07T19:20:29.136210+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-07-07 19:20:29 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2019-07-07T19:20:29.136214+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-07-07T19:20:29.136216+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2019-07-07T19:20:29.136217+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2019-07-07T19:20:29.136219+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
2019-07-07T19:20:29.136220+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2019-07-07T19:20:29.136221+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
2019-07-07T19:20:29.136223+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2019-07-07T19:20:29.136225+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2019-07-07T19:20:29.136226+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2019-07-07T19:20:29.136228+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
2019-07-07T19:20:29.136229+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2019-07-07T19:20:29.136230+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
2019-07-07T19:20:29.136232+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2019-07-07T19:20:29.136233+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
2019-07-07T19:20:29.136235+00:00 app[web.1]: __import__(module)
2019-07-07T19:20:29.136241+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'manage'
2019-07-07T19:20:29.136379+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-07-07 19:20:29 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2019-07-07T19:20:29.139516+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-07-07 19:20:29 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
2019-07-07T19:20:29.146380+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-07-07 19:20:29 +0000] [11] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2019-07-07T19:20:29.146384+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-07-07T19:20:29.146386+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2019-07-07T19:20:29.146387+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2019-07-07T19:20:29.146389+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
2019-07-07T19:20:29.146390+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2019-07-07T19:20:29.146391+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
2019-07-07T19:20:29.146392+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2019-07-07T19:20:29.146394+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2019-07-07T19:20:29.146395+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2019-07-07T19:20:29.146396+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
2019-07-07T19:20:29.146398+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2019-07-07T19:20:29.146399+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
2019-07-07T19:20:29.146400+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2019-07-07T19:20:29.146401+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
2019-07-07T19:20:29.146402+00:00 app[web.1]: __import__(module)
2019-07-07T19:20:29.146508+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'manage'
2019-07-07T19:20:29.146741+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-07-07 19:20:29 +0000] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)
2019-07-07T19:20:29.281982+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-07-07 19:20:29 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2019-07-07T19:20:29.282274+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-07-07 19:20:29 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2019-07-07T20:51:55.336896+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-07-07T20:51:59.172795+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn manage:app`
2019-07-07T20:52:01.295445+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-07-07T20:52:01.261403+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2019-07-07T20:52:01.054611+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-07-07 20:52:01 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
2019-07-07T20:52:01.055203+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-07-07 20:52:01 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:49974 (4)
2019-07-07T20:52:01.055304+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-07-07 20:52:01 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2019-07-07T20:52:01.059960+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-07-07 20:52:01 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2019-07-07T20:52:01.065018+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-07-07 20:52:01 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2019-07-07T20:52:01.065021+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-07-07T20:52:01.065022+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2019-07-07T20:52:01.065023+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2019-07-07T20:52:01.065024+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
2019-07-07T20:52:01.065025+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2019-07-07T20:52:01.065026+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
2019-07-07T20:52:01.065027+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2019-07-07T20:52:01.065028+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2019-07-07T20:52:01.065029+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2019-07-07T20:52:01.065030+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
2019-07-07T20:52:01.065031+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2019-07-07T20:52:01.065032+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
2019-07-07T20:52:01.065033+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2019-07-07T20:52:01.065034+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
2019-07-07T20:52:01.065035+00:00 app[web.1]: __import__(module)
2019-07-07T20:52:01.065039+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'manage'
2019-07-07T20:52:01.065148+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-07-07 20:52:01 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2019-07-07T20:52:01.085990+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-07-07 20:52:01 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
2019-07-07T20:52:01.090957+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-07-07 20:52:01 +0000] [11] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2019-07-07T20:52:01.090959+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-07-07T20:52:01.090960+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2019-07-07T20:52:01.090961+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2019-07-07T20:52:01.090963+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
2019-07-07T20:52:01.090964+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2019-07-07T20:52:01.090965+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
2019-07-07T20:52:01.090966+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2019-07-07T20:52:01.090967+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2019-07-07T20:52:01.090968+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2019-07-07T20:52:01.090969+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
2019-07-07T20:52:01.090970+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2019-07-07T20:52:01.090971+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
2019-07-07T20:52:01.090972+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2019-07-07T20:52:01.090973+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
2019-07-07T20:52:01.090974+00:00 app[web.1]: __import__(module)
2019-07-07T20:52:01.090978+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'manage'
2019-07-07T20:52:01.091103+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-07-07 20:52:01 +0000] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)
2019-07-07T20:52:01.193522+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-07-07 20:52:01 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2019-07-07T20:52:01.193616+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-07-07 20:52:01 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2019-07-07T21:09:26.174326+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=raymoun17.herokuapp.com request_id=2ccdd1b6-cdf6-4a95-8f41-f7f53dcbe033 fwd="41.104.147.72" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-07-07T21:09:26.605404+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=raymoun17.herokuapp.com request_id=ab94815a-226b-4286-859c-738f4595ac0f fwd="41.104.147.72" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-07-07T21:12:39.841954+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=raymoun17.herokuapp.com request_id=dd14b715-3e8d-4c51-ad8f-dc26acde85fa fwd="41.104.147.72" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to run `gunicorn manage:app`. Do you have a file called `manage.py` in the root of your repository? Does it contain the entry point to your application, and does it contain a Flask object named `app`?

Comment: no i am not, i dont even know what gunicorn is

Comment: i was just following a tutorial online on how to deploy flask on heroku and they put the web manage:app on the Procfile @Chris

Comment: @Chris i fixed the issue, in the Procfile i changed manage:app to app:app idk how or why but it worked, regardless thanx for ur help really appriciate it

Comment: I guess your file is called `app.py` then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on that error message, in your `Procfile` you probably have

```
web: gunicorn manage:app
```

This tells the [Gunicorn web server](https://gunicorn.org/) to [run the WSGI callable object called `app` in the `manage` Python module](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/run.html#gunicorn). But it looks like you don't have a `manage` Python module (file).

Change `manage` to whatever module your application lives in. For example, if it is in a file called `server.py`, change your `Procfile` to read

```
web: gunicorn server:app
```

Similarly, if your WSGI callable (probably an instance of `Flask`) is called something other than `app`, change it accordingly.